# Macro to paste value on row's based on column date

Tags: macros

I have in sheet1 a cell A1 where I put in a date (DD/MM/YYYY) in cell B2 is a number the info in cell A1 and B1 change but macro will always copy from B1. On sheet2 on column A are the dates(DD/MM/YYYY) for the whole year one under the other, I want a macro that based on the date in cell A1 on sheet1 looks on sheet2 on column A and copy/pastes the info from B2 on column B from sheet2 on same row with the according date in column A. 
I looked around for similar things but couldn't find anything to work any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

So far I used a pretty simple copy paste macro but using this means I have to write it over and over again for each day of the year.
Where C1 = A1 in Sheet2 witch is first date

```
Sub test()
**Sheets("Sheet1").Select
If Range("A1") = Range("C1") Then
    If Range("B1").Value > "0" Then
        Range("B1").Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        else
        end if
else
end if
end sub
```

So doing it like this I would have to write it again and again for C2..C3.. and put paste to B2.. B3 etc so im looking for a solution to write it just once to look in whole column and paste on the according row.

Comment: please include in your post what you've tried. Also see [stackoverflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to guide you on how to contruct a proper question which will in turn get proper answer.

Comment: Found a solution myself thank you anyway.